# Matlab cos signal from defined frequency course

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

how come the spectrogram of this code is at its max at approximately 4400Hz instead of 2400Hz in the last timestep of the stft? (frequencyCourse(end) = 100, meshingOrder = 24  -> f = 2400)

```
startTime = 0; %s
endTime = 30; %s
startIAS = 15; %Hz
endIAS = 100; %Hz
meshingOrder = 24;
fs = 100000; %Hz
t = startTime:1/fs:endTime-1/fs;
frequencyCourse = linspace(startIAS, endIAS, length(t));
signal = cos(2*pi*meshingOrder*frequencyCourse.*t);
spectrogram(signal, hanning(2^13), 0, 2^14, fs, 'yaxis')
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

It works fine as long as I use chirp instead of my self constructed signal, it's not an option though, since more specific courses are to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

The problem is that the instantaneous phase is the **integral** of the instantaneaous frequency with respect to time, **not** the instantaneous frequency **multiplied** by time.

You should compute the signal as

```
signal = cos(2*pi*meshingOrder*cumtrapz(t, frequencyCourse));
```

## What your code does

In your example, you seem to want to generate a linear chirp with initial frequency `meshingOrder*startIAS` and final frequency `meshingOrder*endIAS`. But that's not the code is doing.

In your computed signal, the instantaneous phase is the argument to the `cos` function:

> `2*pi*meshingOrder*frequencyCourse.*t`

Since the variable `frequencyCourse` increases from `meshingOrder*startIAS` at start time (which is `0`) to `meshingOrder*endIAS` at end time, this can be expressed as

> `2*pi*(A+B*t).*t`

where `A = meshingOrder*startIAS` and `B = meshingOrder*(endIAS-startIAS)/endTime`. Differentiating the instantanous phase with respect to `t` gives an instantaneous frequency

```
A + 2*B*t
```

that is

```
meshingOrder*startIAS + 2*meshingOrder*(endIAS-startIAS)/endTime * t
```

As you can see, the problem is the factor `2` here. At end time the instantaneous frequency is

```
meshingOrder*startIAS + 2*meshingOrder*(endIAS-startIAS)
```

that is

```
2*meshingOrder*endIAS - meshingOrder*startIAS
```

In your example this is 4440 Hz, which is in accordance with your observed value.

## What the code should do

For a linear chirp (or a chirp with any other simple frequency variation, such as a quadratic or exponential) you could compute the correct instantaneous phase that gives rise to the desired instantaneous frequency. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear). This is also what the [`chirp`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/chirp.html) function internally does.

But you seem to be want to deal with **arbitrary frequency courses**. To do that, given arbitrary `t`, just compute the argument of the `cos` as the cumulative integral of `frequencyCourse` with respect to `t`. This is easily done with [`cumtrapz`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html):

```
signal = cos(2*pi*meshingOrder*cumtrapz(t, frequencyCourse));
```

Changing this line in your example gives the following figure, which has the expected frequency variation from 360 Hz to 2400 Hz:

[image]

Comment: Wow could't hope for any better explanation, thanks a lot!

Comment: @hnes Glad you found it useful. It was an interesting question!